# UIWebView iFrame not working as of iOS10

Tags: javascript, ios, uiwebview

I have a UIWebView which contains iFrames that I dynamically load and manipulate with javascript.  My code worked in iOS 5 through 9.  Suddenly it's broken in iOS 10!  Note this is in a cross platform app which also works with various flavors of webviews on Windows, Mac, and Android.  They all work going back to versions of these platforms from many years ago through the present... Apple simply pulled the rug out from under me on this one!

Has anyone else run into new behavior with iFrames as of iOS 10?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem!  The iFrame property "srcdoc" does not work the same in iOS 10.  I have a line of code where I set that property to `null`.  I then set the "src" to some url.  Well, in iOS 10 the src change was not processed and the srcdoc change put the string "null" in the frame.  That's screwy on both accounts!  So, in this particular platform / version the problem was solved by simply dropping my srcdoc assignment altogether. The src assignment is then respected. I left it in place as it was for all my other webviews since this always worked before!

Watch out if you use both srcdoc and src in iOS apparently!